# Making a <div> slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, web, slideshow

I am looking to create a  slideshow. What I mean by that is that I want to create one of those things that you sometimes see on websites where you have a row of buttons at the bottom, and clicking on those buttons fades you to an image or a  element, but if you do not touch those buttons, they switch in order between one another. How can I make something like this? I am new to web development, and help would be much appreciated. I am aware that this task will require JavaScript, however I would like to avoid jQuery if at all possible, I will still consider suggestions made using jQuery, so please don't hesitate to post them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any way to do this with HTML/CSS alone, though I could be wrong. When I was first starting web development I found it useful to look at code from Twitter Bootstrap to figure out how they managed to create certain effects/elements.

If I understand what you want correctly, I think you are looking for [Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel). Take a look at that and hopefully it'll help. You can even use bootstrap if you'd like.

Good luck.

Comment: @MituIP91 Thank you for the suggestion. The link that you gave is exactly what I am looking for, but I would rather have an image fade as opposed to the sliding effect that the example that you showed gives.

Answer (score 0):

Google Jquery Sliders or Gallerys.

Or CSS sliders

- http://www.queness.com/post/14329/pure-css3-sliders-and-tutorials
- http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/tools/awesome-jquery-sliders/

You dont need to know any jquery to be able to get a working slider. Read the Documentation and look at the example files to get started. If you use jquery make sure you link your files to the document correctly.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to try making one myself, but I will use these as resources in order to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple jQuery carousel which slides automatically.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/AtFeF/)**

The code is very simple and easy to use as well.

**HTML**

*Just a DIV with images inside*

```
<div id="banner_area">
    <img class="active" src="image1.png" />
    <img src="image2.png" />
    <img src="image3.png" />
    <img src="image4.png" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

*CSS is pretty straight forward as well*

```
#banner_area img 
{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
}
#banner_area img:first-child 
{
    display:block;
}
#banner_area > img /* Use this to resize all image's container */
{
    width:400px;
    height:250px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

*Don't forget to include jQuery as well // You can increase/decrease the time*

```
function cycleImages() {
    var images = $('#banner_area img'),
        now = images.filter(':visible'),
        next = now.next().length ? now.next() : images.first(),
        speed = 1000;

    now.fadeOut(speed);
    next.fadeIn(speed);
}

$(function () {
    setInterval(cycleImages, 1400);
});
```